# Utenti is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Error:  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Utenti is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Utenti AS o WHERE 1=1 ]

```java
public List<Utenti> selectAllUtenti() {
    String query = "SELECT o FROM Utenti AS o WHERE 1=1 ";
    TypedQuery<Utenti> q = em.createQuery(query, Utenti.class);
    List<Utenti> lista = q.getResultList();
    if (lista == null || lista.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return lista;
}
```

Comment: Utenti.java -> @Entity
@Table(name = "utenti")
public class Utenti extends BaseBean {

Comment: Utenti and utenti is a different table

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
      SELECT o FROM Utenti o

Also check if you use proper annotations, for example you should use

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
```

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Utenti is not mapped [SELECT o FROM Utenti o]

Comment: Check if your annotations are correct, and hibernate.cfg.xml file if you use it.